# LPX-00217: invalid character 15576961 (U+EDAF81) - How to find the invalid character by Notepad or Notedpad++?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, oracle

I got error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00217: invalid character 15576961 (U+EDAF81)
```

---

I have xml file with customer sensitive data. How to find the invalid character 15576961 (U+EDAF81) by Notepad or Notedpad++ and then will remove it.
Or any solution.
Could you help to suggest/correct me, please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it really an invalid character or is the `encoding` stating something different than the files was saved?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I used UTF-8 encoding. I found the character in https://unicodelookup.com/#15576961/1. Please note I removed it from my input file and currently it's no error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking the xml file and found the invalid character  by Notedpad++ and can removed it.